# How to get multiple input values inside one DataTables column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTables which I need to set 2 inputs in the same column. I know how to get the value if there is one input per column as below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {       
    var cell = table.cell({ row: rowIdx, column: 0 }).node();

    console.log($('input', cell).val());
});
```

How can I get the two values?

```
table.cell({row: rowIdx, column:0}).node().find('#inputOne');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the values to array

```
var values = $(cell).find(':input').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get();
console.log(values);
```